# How to keep empty cells as empty in JSON output instead of ignore the cell (Vue-XLSX)

Tags: json, excel, vue.js, nuxt.js, xlsx

I'm reading a excel file and converting it to JSON object using [vue-xlsx](https://vue-xlsx.netlify.app/guide/#quick-start) in a Nuxt project. But there can be empty cells. Vue-xlsx ignores them.

[image]

Returned JSON object is like this:

```json
[ 
  { "Header1": "a", "Header3": "c" }, 
  { "Header1": "d", "Header2": "e", "Header3": "f" }, 
  { "Header1": "g", "Header2": "h", "Header3": "i" } 
]
```

I don't need to print this using 'xlsx-table' component because I need JSON object.
Tried to pass [defval](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#json) property as options on this way. But not success.

```html
<section>
  <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
  <xlsx-read :options="options" :file="file">
    <xlsx-json :sheet="selectedSheet" >
      <template #default="{collection}">
        <!-- <xlsx-table :sheet="selectedSheet" /> -->
        <div>
          {{ json = collection }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </xlsx-json>
  </xlsx-read>
</section>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      options: {
        defval: "",
      },
      json: null,
      selectedSheet: 0,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

I need some help to generate this kind of JSON object:
[image]

How Can I do this with **Vue-XLSX**.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with VanillaJS, no need to rely on `vue-xlxs` on this one.

If we do start from

```json
[ 
  { "Header1": "a", "Header3": "c" }, 
  { "Header1": "d", "Header2": "e", "Header3": "f" }, 
  { "Header1": "g", "Header2": "h", "Header3": "i" } 
]
```

We can have the following

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      array: [
        { Header1: 'a', Header3: 'c' },
        { Header1: 'd', Header2: 'e', Header3: 'f' },
        { Header1: 'g', Header2: 'h', Header3: 'i' },
      ],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const neededHeaders = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
    const arrayWithFallback = this.array.map((row) => {
      for (const headerKey of neededHeaders) {
        if (!(headerKey in row)) {
          // if you're missing one of the header, let's create a default value for it
          row[headerKey] = 'your-fallback-here' // can also be an empty string of course
        }
      }
      return row
    })
    console.log('arrayWithFallback', arrayWithFallback)
  },
}
</script>
```

And it'll create this at the end

```json
[
  { "Header1": "a", "Header2": "your-fallback-here", "Header3": "c" },
  { "Header1": "d", "Header2": "e", "Header3": "f" },
  { "Header1": "g", "Header2": "h", "Header3": "i" }
]
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode headings in the code. Because sometimes headings can be change with modifications in the file.

Comment: @LahiruMadushan then, you could make a quick search with the longest object available in your array, take it's keys and use it as the headers (will be dynamic this way).

Comment: But if there was a one field which is all records with empty, process will break. is it @kissu..?

Comment: Can't we take a solution from 'vue-xlxs' library to consider those values too..?

Comment: @LahiruMadushan I mean, you can try this out and fix it through code if it's still buggy, since at the end of the day, you can edit the data to your liking. I've posted a github issue to see if `defval` can be used but I'm not sure it will be: https://github.com/DonNicoJs/vue-xlsx/issues/19 Feel free to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I used "parsed" event that was mentioned in the [documentation](https://vue-xlsx.netlify.app/components/xlsx-to-js.html#xlsx-json) for "xlsx-json" component. Here is the full Nuxt component for me:

> If you have the "header info":

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Import XLSX</h3>
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
    <xlsx-read :file="file">
      <xlsx-json @parsed = "parsFunc">
        <template #default="{collection}">
          <div class="divShow">
            {{ collection }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </xlsx-json>
    </xlsx-read>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/* put the address that matches for your app */
import { XlsxRead, XlsxJson } from "~/node_modules/vue-xlsx/dist/vue-xlsx.es.js";

export default {
  components: {
    XlsxRead,
    XlsxJson
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      /* this array contains the exact words that you write on the first line of xlsx file */
      headerData: ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3"],
    };
  },

  computed: {
      lengData: function() {
          return this.headerData.length;
      } 
  }, 

  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
    },

    sortOutput(elemEach) {
        /* this function sorts the new object */
        let arrObj = Object.entries(elemEach);
        arrObj.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        let arraySorted = Object.fromEntries(arrObj);
        return arraySorted; 
    },

    parsFunc(event) {
        /* this function loops throught elements in "xlsx" file and replaces empty cells with "" */
        let counter = 0;
        event.forEach(element => {
            for (let it = 0; it < this.lengData; it++) {
                
                if( element[this.headerData[it]] == undefined ) {
                    element[this.headerData[it]] = "";
                }
                
            }

            let sortedElem = this.sortOutput(element);
            
            event[counter] = sortedElem;
            
            counter++;
        }); // end of forEach
    
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* this is the styles that I used */
.divShow {
    background-color: #865611;
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

> If you want to dynamically generate the "header info":

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Import XLSX</h3>
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
    <xlsx-read :file="file">
      <xlsx-json @parsed = "parsFunc">
        <template #default="{collection}">
          <div class="divShow">
            {{ collection }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </xlsx-json>
    </xlsx-read>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/* put the address that matches for your app */
import { XlsxRead, XlsxJson } from "~/node_modules/vue-xlsx/dist/vue-xlsx.es.js";

export default {
  components: {
    XlsxRead,
    XlsxJson
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      headerData: [],
    };
  },

  computed: {
      lengData: function() {
          return this.headerData.length;
      } 
  }, 

  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
    },

    findHeader(elem, newArr) {
      /* this function finds the headers of the "xlsx" file */
      this.headerData = [];
      let convertArr = Object.entries(elem);
      convertArr.forEach(element2 => {
      newArr.push( Object.entries(element2[1]).length );
      });

      let indexOfMaxValue = newArr.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMax] ? i : iMax, 0);
      
      let arrayExtract =  Object.entries( convertArr[indexOfMaxValue][1] );

      arrayExtract.forEach(element3 => {
        this.headerData.push(element3[0]);
      });

      this.replaceEmpty(elem);

    },

    sortOutput(elemEach) {
        /* this function sorts the new object */
        let arrObj = Object.entries(elemEach);
        arrObj.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        let arraySorted = Object.fromEntries(arrObj);
        return arraySorted; 
    },

    parsFunc(event) {
        /* this function acts after submitting file and call another function to find "headers" */
        let emptyArr = [];
        this.findHeader(event, emptyArr);
    },

    replaceEmpty: function(eventPass) {
      /* this function loops throught elements in "xlsx" file and replaces empty cells with "" */
      let counter = 0;
      eventPass.forEach(element => {
          
            for (let it = 0; it < this.lengData; it++) {
                
              if( element[this.headerData[it]] == undefined ) {
                      element[this.headerData[it]] = "";
              }
                
            }

            let sortedElem = this.sortOutput(element);
            
            eventPass[counter] = sortedElem;
            
            counter++;
        }); // end of forEach

    } // end of replaceEmpty

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* this is the styles that I used */
.divShow {
    background-color: #865611;
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

But for working on this version, you must have at least **one** full row in your **xlsx** file. For example this code does not work for this kind of **xlsx** file:

[image]

Comment: hamid-davodi I cannot hardcode headings in the code. Because sometimes headings can be change with modifications in the file.

Comment: Yes the code I wrote needs to have the "headings" info. I will add another code that does not need hardcode "headings".